# Assembly DIV operation with prior value in edx

Tags: assembly, machine-code, low-level-code

I'm so new to assembly and I had this example in the book i'm learning from

```
%include "io.inc"

section .text
global CMAIN
CMAIN:
mov ebp, esp;
    ;write your code here
    mov eax, 444444447h
    mov ebx, 22222222h
    mov edx, 44h
    div ebx
    ret
```

And those are the results I'm getting 
[run_results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/trm2T.png)

```
EAX: 0x200
EBX: 0x22222222
EDX: 0x47
```

*can anyone explain to me why the final value in the **EDX** is *0x47* ?
*And when I put *0h* in the **EDX** why the final value in the **EAX** is becoming *0x2* ?
*how is the **EDX** effecting the division results, if basically the division is just between **EAX** and **EBX**.
*Isn't the **EDX** just for storing the devision rest?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: _EDX_ will contain the remainder of the division. _EAX_ contains the quotient. Division by a 32-bit operand will divide a 64-bit value (dividend in EDX:EAX) by a 32-bit value (in this case EBX is the divisor).

Comment: What leads you to think that division is just between `eax` and `ebx`? Guessing? Don't do that in assembly, it doesn't work very logically. Most of the time it does, but when it does not, it bites hard. Rather just check the [docs](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/DIV.html) (or the full Intel docs).